Redisson RBitSet: Function `asBitSet()` load all BitSet
I'm currently using RBitSet from Redisson
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.11.5/org/redisson/api/RBitSet.html
From the link, I find there is a function asBitSet()
From my test, I can understand that: this function use Redis Command Get with ByteArrayCodec --> And convert ByteArray to BitSet
My question: Is there more to this function, why there isn't any document or comment on this function? Is it safe to use in Production Env
